# page transition like iphone app feedly on phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, transition

Can anybody recommend a plugin,css3 or javascript library which will allow me to implement the same page transition (scroll up&down) as the iphone app Feedly?

To be used in phonegap as html5 app.

jquery mobile didn't work will

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get what your asking for ? 
As in the style of Titlebar and Tab Bar ? They can be achieved natively using Phonegap plugins - a google for that will find it pretty quick.

Otherwise for natural touch based slides between pages I recommend IOS Slider as it works well.
http://iosscripts.com/iosslider/

If this helped upvote or accept as the answer.